# Artisan: "Command not found"

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

So I try to add a Command with

```
php artisan command:make MailSendCommand
```

The file MailSendCommand.php is created.
I edited it to this:

```
class MailSendCommand extends Command {

    protected $name = 'command:send-mail';

    protected $description = 'Send mails to the users.';


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function fire()
    {
        $this->info('Befehl wird ausgeführt' );
    }
...
```

In my file start/artisan.php I added

```
Artisan::add(new MailSendCommand);
```

but when I enter 'php artisan command:send-mail' it says:

```
Command "command:send-mail" is not defined.
```

It just worked on my Home PC (XAMPP) but not on my live server (PHP 5.5.15 (cgi-fcgi))

'php artisan clear:cache' and 'php artisan dump-autoload' did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the problem is related to your setup. You're using PHP CGI instead of CLI to run your commands which will not work.

Ensure that the code is there on your live environment and run your commands on CLI, as these are command line scripts.

Answer (score 4):

Go to `app/Console/Kernel.php` and add the class to the `commands` variable. It would look something like:

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\MyCustomCommand::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')
        //          ->hourly();
    }
}
```

Here i added `MyCustomCommand` as a valid artisan command. Check it is among available commands executing:

```
php artisan list
```

Comment: Still works 5 years later. Strange how the setup of the artisan command is not explained in a tutorials... Thanks for your help